# How to get rows count of internal table in abap?

Tags: abap

How do I get the row count of an internal table? I guess that I can loop on it. But there must be a saner way.

I don't know if it makes a difference but the code should run on 4.6c version.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use the following function:

```
 DESCRIBE TABLE <itab-Name> LINES <variable>
```

After the call, variable contains the number of rows of the internal table .

Answer (score 98):

There is also a built-in function for this task:

```
variable = lines( itab_name ).
```

Just like the "pure" ABAP syntax described by [IronGoofy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25320/irongoofy), the function "lines( )" writes the number of lines of table itab_name into the variable.

Comment: This one is vastly superior to `describe` due to the fact you can use as an inline operation. For instance: `If lines ( itab ) > 0. itab[ 1 ]-text = 'Potato'. endif.` or `coeff = lines( lt_relevant ) / lines( lt_all )`.

Answer (score 14):

Beside the recommended

```
DESCRIBE TABLE <itab-Name> LINES <variable>
```

there is also the system variable `SY-TFILL`.

From documentation:

> After the statements DESCRIBE TABLE, LOOP AT and READ TABLE, the number of rows of the accessed internal table.

Example script:

```
REPORT ytest.

DATA pf_exclude TYPE TABLE OF sy-ucomm WITH HEADER LINE.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  APPEND '1' TO pf_exclude.
  APPEND '2' TO pf_exclude.
  APPEND '3' TO pf_exclude.
  APPEND '4' TO pf_exclude.

  WRITE: / 'sy-tfill = ', sy-tfill.

  DESCRIBE TABLE pf_exclude.
  WRITE: / 'sy-tfill = ', sy-tfill, 'after describe table'.

  sy-tfill = 0. "Reset
  READ TABLE pf_exclude INDEX 1 TRANSPORTING NO FIELDS.
  WRITE: / 'sy-tfill = ', sy-tfill, 'after read table'.


  sy-tfill = 0. "Reset
  LOOP AT pf_exclude.
    WRITE: / 'sy-tfill = ', sy-tfill, 'in loop with', pf_exclude.
    sy-tfill = 0. "Reset
  ENDLOOP.
```

The result:

```
sy-tfill =           0
sy-tfill =           4  after describe tabl
sy-tfill =           4  after read table
sy-tfill =           4  in loop with 1
sy-tfill =           0  in loop with 2
sy-tfill =           0  in loop with 3
sy-tfill =           0  in loop with 4
```

Please get attention of the value 0 for the 2nd entry: `SY-TFILL` is not updated with each step, only after the first loop.

I recommend the usage SY-TFILL only, if you need it direct after the `READ`(1)... If there are other commands between the `READ` and the usage of SY-TFILL, there is always the danger of a change of the system variable.

(1) or describe table.

Answer (score 3):

```
  DATA : V_LINES TYPE I. "declare variable
  DESCRIBE TABLE <ITAB> LINES V_LINES. "get no of rows
  WRITE:/ V_LINES. "display no of rows
```

Refreance:
http://www.sapnuts.com/courses/core-abap/internal-table-work-area.html

Answer (score 0):

The functional module EM_GET_NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES will also provide the row count. It takes 1 parameter - the table name.

Comment: This function modules allows you to read the number of rows in a database table. The question was about the rows of an internal table.

Answer (score -1):

you can also use OPEN Sql to find the number of rows using the COUNT Grouping clause and also there is system field SY-LINCT to count the lines(ROWS) of your table.

Comment: Guys, an internal table ( per the question ), is not a database table. COUNT is for counting lines in a database table ( hence not relevant to the question ).

Answer (score -2):

if I understand your question correctly, you want to know the row number during a conditional loop over an internal table. 
You can use the system variable sy-tabix if you work with internal tables. Please refer to the ABAP documentation if you need more information (especially the chapter on [internal table processing](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/EN/fc/eb36bb358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/frameset.htm)).

Example:

```
LOOP AT itab INTO workarea
        WHERE tablefield = value.

     WRITE: 'This is row number ', sy-tabix.

ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Use sy-tabix carefully, it is updated on every call to LOOP, READ TABLE... and sometimes it can have an unexpected value.

Answer (score -2):

```
data: vcnt(4).

clear vcnt.

LOOP at itab WHERE value = '1'.
  add 1 to vcnt.
ENDLOOP.
```

The answer will be `3. (vcnt = 3).`

Comment: -1, this is CPU intensive and much worse than using `DESCRIBE` or `lines( )`.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think there is a SAP parameter for that kind of result. Though the code below will deliver.

```
LOOP AT intTab.

  AT END OF value.

    result = sy-tabix.

    write result.  

  ENDAT.

ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: -1, this is CPU intensive and much worse than using `DESCRIBE` or `lines( )`.